# Single Page Application Form

Tags: php, html

I have a multiple page web application that needs to be changed to a single page web application.

My form to create an input works, but it always brings the user to a blank page when you click submit.

Is there something I can do so that it would stay on this page and just pop up an alert message?

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<title> CRUD</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> CRUD Management</h1>

<!--Create Row-->
<h2> Create new Entry </h2>
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="ID">ID:</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="creator">Creator:</label>
        <input type="text" name="creator" id="creator">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    </p>
     <p>
        <label for="type">Type:</label>
        <input type="text" name="type" id="type">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="identifier">Identifier:</label>
        <input type="text" name="identifier" id="identifier">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="language">Language:</label>
        <input type="text" name="language" id="language">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" action="insert.php" method="post">
</form>
<table>
<h2>Retrieve Data</h2>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</td>
                <th>Creator</td>
                <th>Title</td>
                <th>Type</td>
                <th>Date</td>
                <th>Identifier</td>
                <th>Language</td>
                <th>Description</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['creator']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['title']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['type']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['date']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['identifier']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['language']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['description']?></td>
                </tr>

        </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>



<a href="/a3/createForm.html" target="_parent"><button>Create</button></a>

<a href="/a3/retrieve.php" target="_parent"><button>Retrieve</button></a>

<a href="/a3/updateForm.html" target="_parent"><button>Update</button></a>

<a href="/a3/deleteForm.html" target="_parent"><button>Delete</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "some-database";
// Create connection
$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($link === false) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 
$ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['id']);
$creator = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['creator']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['type']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['title']);
$identifier = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['identifier']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date']);
$language = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['language']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['description']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO ebook_metadata (id, creator, title, type, identifier, date, language, description)
VALUES ('$ID', '$creator', '$title', '$type', '$identifier', '$date', '$language','$description')";

/* if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
} */

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Javascript / Ajax.

Comment: there are a lot of errors here. One of which; `<input type="submit" value="Submit" action="insert.php" method="post">`

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense bud. You need to understand how to create a form and send variables to php (first of all). The second problem is you are getting blank, probably because you haven't the environment configured with PHP to be used and database. Try to do a search to understand the concept.

Comment: I've never seen a form action placed on an input like that, if you want a single page site, don't have any action associated to the form and place the php above your html.

Comment: `<form   action="insert.php" method="post">` edit that -- and button `<p><input type="submit"  value="Submit"></p>`  `</form>`

Comment: Try to search some form example first. You may use form/button combo as #Funk Forty Niner and #dean shows. Do you use this code in form? Because there are 2 </html> lines, this is not a valid code.

Answer (score 0):

First learn how to use forms in HTML, then come back here and look at this solution of the problem you are describing:

In order to prevent a `<form>` from going to a new page or reloading it, the simplest solution is to use `return false;` in the `onsubmit` listener and handle your submission over JavaScript:

```
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(this); return false;">
```